# Am I allowed to make an app that allows users to like Facebook pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want to create an app that simply allows a user to log in, touch a like button, and then the app logs them out. I am wondering if this type of app would be allowed by Facebook, since the main functionality is all Facebook related. The app would be used by business to help them increase their Facebook page following. Is this allowed?

Comment: why would you write an app for this? the facebook like button already handles every aspect of that and all you'd need to do is link the fb jssdk into your page and drop the like button wherever you want it.

Comment: Yeah but you have to write some code on your app, using the FB API, in order to achieve that. I think that's what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @Renan no, if you use the fb like button plugin it handles all authentication. you don't need to write a single line of javascript.

Comment: Yeah, the like button and like box are 1 line of code each after you add the Javascript SDK, which itself is a simple copy/paste job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are. Pratically every `like` button you see in blog posts and product pages in online stores works like that (except for the logout).

Comment: This showed up in my Facebook developer account, which is really why I asked the question in the first place. 

My app is currently using the following deprecated features:
Social Plugins (Like Button, Like Box) without absolute URL's in their `href` parameter.
I want to create an app that a business can choose the FB page they want liked in the settings, which is then entered in the like button code. When they upgraded their SDK, I was sent this. I just wanted to make sure this app would be compliant with their rules.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the parameters, not in the usage of the features themselves.